# Creating files on disk from a jar

Tags: java, file, jar

My problem is that whenever I run my program from Eclipse or IntelliJ I can create as many files in a specific folder but when I create a jar it only creates one file no matter how many times I call the method that does this.
In detail a feature of a program allows the user to create a file in the folder where the jar is executed from. This is done through a class containing static fields and methods.
The fields in the class are:

```
private static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
private static Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
private static BufferedWriter bw;
private static String filesFolderPath;
```

First I get the path to the jar:

```
private static String getJarPath() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    URL url = PrintHelper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    String jarPath = URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(), "UTF-8");
    String path = new File(jarPath).getParentFile().getPath();
    return path;
}
```

Then I set the path to the folder I want the files to be put in and create that folder through a static block in the class so that this code is executed only once when the class is first used:

```
 static
 {
    try
    {   
        String dirPath = getJarPath();                 
        String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        filesFolderPath = dirPath + fileSeparator + "files" + fileSeparator;

        File file = new File(filesFolderPath);
        file.mkdir();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally. each time a user wants to create a file this method is called:

```
   public static void print(String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File(filesFolderPath, getFileName(filename));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        //writing with the buffered writer
        bw.close();
    }
```

Is there any reason for this to work as I want it when run from an IDE and create only one file when running from the jar?

Comment: Log or print the values of the paths in each case, to see the differences. BTW, I doubt you really want to use `.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`, but since you do not explain what you want to do (or where do you want the files), we cannot help any more.

Comment: I just want to create a folder where the jar is located and put the files there. It works the first time I try to create a file and then it doesn't, but I will do what you suggested.    
P.S. The path to the folder where the files should be created doesn't change as expected. It is what is stored from the very beginning in the private static String filesFolderPath; field